# Why am I getting no answers in recent questions? Are the tags not perfectly suitable?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Apart from a question which indeed required a very long answer, why does [Any general hints on how to prove that two functions$\ f(n)$ and$\ g(m_1,m_2,...,m_{28})$ never have a common natural divisor?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/968121/any-general-hints-on-how-to-prove-that-two-functions-fn-and-gm-1-m-2) have no answers? I had thought it would have been easily answered, it seems way easier to me, but I doubt it'll recieve any in these conditions. I'm seeing only a few views. What's wrong with it?

P.S. It is also true that I'd like an answer as soon as possible, since together with the other question, I've been waiting for a while, and I really need this.

Comment: Maybe this may be somewhat interesting for you: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3865/depending-on-the-tag-is-there-a-possibility-to-know-on-which-days-and-hours-are (and probably also other posts shown there among linked questions).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm seeing only a few views.

That already explains what is going on: it's not that the question is bad, it's just that few people are looking at questions right now.

Saturday evening in the Americas, night in Europe, weekend everywhere.

Comment: Yeah, I guess you're right.

Comment: Does your new username mean I can force you to fail?